# Convert NSSet to Swift Array

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

In CoreData I have defined an *unordered* to-many relationship. This relationship is defined in Swift like this:

```
@NSManaged var types : NSMutableSet
```

However, to use Swift at it's best, I want to use a normal Swift array like `Type[]`. However, CoreData forces me to use `NS(Mutable)Set`. How can I type-cast / convert the `NSSet` to `Array<Type>[]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert NSArray to Swift array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422840/convert-nsarray-to-swift-array)

Comment: Type-cast is not possible since NSSet doesn't inherit NSArray, but you can convert to NSArray with `types.allObjects()`

Comment: @ColinE it's not a duplicate as the one you're referring to is about **NSArray** and this is about **NSSet**. Different types, different question and probably different answers.

Comment: yes, that is duplicate, because the `NSSet` can be converted `NSArray` and the solution is the same from that point.

Comment: @holex, well actually that's not true either. NSSet can be converted to an Array, as shown in the answers below. However NSArray doesn't appear to have an 'easy' cast / convert to Array.

Comment: @bouke, the _Swift_ documentation says the following about Cocoa Types: _Swift automatically bridges between the `Array` type and the `NSArray` class._, and _(...)in Swift code, you can pass an `Array` value to a method expecting an `NSArray` object. You can also cast between a bridged type and its counterpart._, I guess that is quite clear statement, source: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html, and you are welcome!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

*As of Xcode 7.2 with Swift 2.1.1*

Actually, I found out by trial that:

```
@NSManaged var types : Set<Type>
```

Works perfectly fine.

The fact is that CoreData generates somethink like:

```
@NSManaged var types : NSSet
```

when creating a `NSManagedObject` subclass from the editor. So I was wondering if there was a not very verbose method to use the `filter` method without casting. But then Swift is supposed to bridge automatically between NSSet, NSArray and their counterparts. So I tried declaring it directly as a Set and it works.

Answering the question, converting it to an Array becomes trivial:

```
Array(types)
```

Comment: Core Data uses NSSet to optimise things under the hood. It might be less memory efficient to use Set even though the ergonomic is better.

Answer (score 101):

```
var set = NSSet() //NSSet
var arr = set.allObjects //Swift Array
var nsarr = set.allObjects as NSArray  //NSArray
```

Comment: While this answer is still valid, Swift 1.2 now also contains a native `Set` structure. The `Set` doesn't have `allObjects`, but supports (most) operations that an array would support. So there is less need to convert a NSSet to array.

Comment: This really helped me with my collectionview - I used it to allow my CoreData NSSet to drive my collectionView via indexpath.row

Comment: To expand on the comment @bouke posted, you can convert a Swift `Set` to `Array` like `let array = Array(mySet)`

Answer (score 16):

This is how I did it:

```
let array = object.NSSet?.allObjects as! [ArrayType]
```

Then you can manipulate the array as normal:

```
for item in array {
    id = item.id
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use map to get array like this:

```
extension NSSet {
  func toArray<T>() -> [T] {
    let array = self.map({ $0 as! T})
    return array
  }
}

...
let myArray: [MyType] = set.toArray()
```

Answer (score 8):

This answer is outdated as of Xcode 7.2/Swift 2.1. See the accepted answer for an updated answer.

---

I'm currently using `obj.types.allObjects as Type[]`, but that feels like a hack/workaround.

Comment: It's alright man, in Swift 1.2 a native `Set` will be introduced so a workaround is fine at the time being.

Comment: As of Xcode 7, Swift 2. **CoreData** stil uses `NSSet`, so this very set till needs to be turned into either a native **Array** or native **Set**.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Actually, as of Xcode 7.2 (I haven't tried other versions), it works if you declare it directly as a native `Set` as I explain in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the details. +1. You may want to be specific about Xcode version in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use .sortedArray to sort the elements.

Swift 3:

```
yourNSSetType?.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "keyToSortBy", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSNumber.compare(_:)))]) as! [yourNSSetType]
```

For strings, use NSString.compare in the #selector call.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @David for his solution
I had the same situation
In my current project, we still use Objective C with swift bridging for the coredata modules
so in my case, I had to use the following as compiler can't intervene what is the Generic Type to convert i had to pass it with using actually :(

```
extension Set {
    
    func toArray<S>(_ of: S.Type) -> [S] {
        let array = self.map({$0 as! S})
        return array
    }
    
}
```

and using:

```
Items?.toArray(XYZ.self)
```

in my Managed object; variable was like this for reference

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSSet<XYZ *> * items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with a ForEach view in SwiftUI

```
ForEach(object.allObjects as! [ObjectType], id: \.self)
{ obj in
    Text("\(obj.name)")
}
```

XCode 14.2, targeting iOS 16.2