# Convert NSArray to Swift Array<T>

Tags: core-data, swift, ios8

In CoreData I have defined an *ordered* to-many relationship. This relationship is defined in Swift like this:

```
@NSManaged var types : NSMutableArray
```

However, to use Swift at it's best, I want to use a normal Swift array like `Type[]`. However, CoreData forces me to use `NS(Mutable)Array`. How can I type-cast / convert the `NSArray` to `Array<Type>[]`?

Apparently the confusion arises from the following error:

```
let array = obj.types as T[] // Cannot convert expression's type 'Node[]' to type '$T2'
```

While this is accepted by the editor:

```
let array = obj.types as AnyObject[] as T[] // No complaint
```

Comment: An ordered relationship is (as far as I know) represented by an NSOrderedSet, not by an NSMutableArray.

Comment: "I'm currently using obj.types.allObjects as Type[], but that feels like a hack/workaround". No, that _is_ how you cast an NSArray to a Swift array of a specific type.

Comment: Wow, why the downvotes? I have the same question and it does seem worthy of asking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I'm currently using `obj.types.allObjects as Type[]`, but that feels like a hack/workaround.

Then revise your feelings. What you're doing is exactly how you *do* "type-cast / convert the `NSArray` to `Array<Type>[]`."

An NSArray always arrives into Swift as containing `AnyObject` (i.e. an `Array<AnyObject>`, aka `AnyObject[]`). Casting it down to a specific type, if you know that it contains all one type, is up to you, and how you are doing it is exactly what you are supposed to do.

**EDIT** In Swift 2.0 and the new iOS 9 APIs, an NSArray will often arrive correctly typed, and no cast will be needed.

**EDIT 2** In Swift 3.0, an NSArray that is not correctly typed, though uncommon, will arrive as containing `Any` instead of `AnyObject` and will still have to be cast down to a specific type.

Comment: That 'workaround' is not valid for NSArray, but for NSSet. So I'm still looking for a nice solution.

Comment: it is valid for an array -allObjects is a method on NSSet that returns all elements as an array.

Comment: Admitted, I was expecting an `allObjects` on NSArray; but NSArray itself can be casted to an Array. However I'm still unclear of why two casts are required, see my updated question.

Comment: Using swift 2.2, the cast is still needed in order to properly use the map function.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a working piece of code from one of my projects that might help?

```
if let rawArray = rawData as? NSArray,
   let castArray = rawArray as? Array< Dictionary< String, AnyObject > >
   { 
       // etc... 
   }
```

It works, although I'm not sure it would be considered optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate them that way :

```
for type in types.array {
    // Do something
}
```

Or use simply the `array` property of the `NSOrderedSet` you are using, like so :

```
types.array
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a new generic array and manually populate it as follows:

```
    var result = Type[]()

    for item : AnyObject in self {
        //  Keep only objC objects compatible with OutType
        if let converted = bridgeFromObjectiveC(item, Type.self) {
            result.append(converted)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Iterating over an array to copy it to a new array doesn't seem very elegant to me. Is this the most simple solution, even when I know all the instances in the array will be of the same type?