# How to Convert NSMutable Array to Swift Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, nsmutablearray

I am adding ID's to `NSMutableArray` after that i want this `MutableArrray` as a Swift Array.

here's my code:

```
var categories = NSMutableArray()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        if (!categoryTable.hidden)
        {
            print("select multiple categories")

            categoryList = categoryData[indexPath.row]

            categories.addObject(["\(categoryList!.categoryID)"])

        }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        let listCategoryID = categoryData[indexPath.row]

        for category in categories as [AnyObject]
        {

            if("\(listCategoryID.categoryID)" == category.objectAtIndex!(0) as! String)
            {

                categories.removeObject(category)
            }
        }
        print("Catgeory ID \(categories)")

    }

// Convert NSMutableArray To Swift Array
@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        let catgID = categories as AnyObject as! [String]
}
```

**Output I am Getting: Category ID ( ( 27 ), ( 26 ) )**

***Output I want : ["27","26"]***

Comment: try `for category in categories as [String]`

Comment: @iYoung thanks bro, i got the same solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSArray to Swift Array<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422840/convert-nsarray-to-swift-arrayt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var catg_id:[Int] = []
        for category in categories as [AnyObject]
        {
            catg_id.append(Int(category.objectAtIndex!(0) as! NSNumber))

        }
```

Comment: You wanted to get output in string or int?